# Freeze a JavaScript?

Tags: css, facebook, firebug

I'm making a custom CSS theme for Facebook and I'm trying to view the CSS code for the little pop-up that happens when you hover your cursor over someones profile picture. I'm using Firebug to view the CSS code. It's viewable, but I cannot view the CSS code fully, because once I take my cursor off the profile picture, the pop-up disappears, then Firebug doesn't display the CSS code used for it. So is there a way to freeze open the JS so when I take my cursor off it doesn't go away? Or is there anyway to freeze the pop-up open?

Comment: Doesn't firebug provide a way to simply set a checkbox to tell the element it is being hovered instead of actually having to hover it?

Comment: @PeeHaa - Thanks for the reply and thread. I looked about it and it makes sense, but isn't working. Wouldn't I click the first line it displays and then use the "hover" option?

Comment: I can provide you an answer for Chrome. Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome:

1. Go to Facebook
2. Press **F12** to open *Chrome Developer Tools*
3. Go to the *Sources* tab (helper screenshot below):
   [image]
4. After having clicked on the *Sources* tab described previously, make sure you **DON'T** click anywhere on the page. Go hover over a profile picture, and while the pop-up is open, hit **F8** and move the mouse a little bit (like 1 pixel).

The page should now be frozen. You can go to the *Elements* tab, press **CTRL+F** and search for some text that's inside the pop-up. This way, you will see the corresponding HTML and you will be able to view without constraints the CSS.

If you want to resume, you can go back to the *Sources* tab, and hit the resume button on the right.